# Betrayal Haunt #38 How Many Firebats?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

I played Betrayal at House on the Hill for the first time on the weekend. I was the traitor and it was haunt #38. I followed my interpretation of what the book said, which when the first person died read, and then said I did it wrong.

*Note: The version is not the newest*

The text (from memory):

> Place as many firebats as there are players in the room where the Haunt started

My interpretation:

> Place 6 (total players) firebats in the room where the Haunt started

Their interpretation:

> Place 1 (number of players in the room where the Haunt started) firebat in the room where the Haunt started.

**Newest revision**

> Get out a number of firebats (represented by
>   orange Bat tokens) equal to half the number
>   of players, rounded up. Put them in the room
>   where the haunt was revealed.

Was my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your interpretation was correct. There are several haunts where it refers to "as many things as there are players". While the sentence is grammatically ambiguous, the other interpretation would be very strange because there wil always be only 1 player in the room where the Haunt started; the player who revealed the Haunt. So if that's what they meant, then they could have just said "place 1 firebat in the room..."

Also, the newer revision seems to confirm that the number of firebat is meant to be based on the number of players; though obviously they felt the traitor needed to be nerfed.

One other "proof"... if "players in the room where the Haunt started" were meant as all one clause, then there's nothing at all in the sentence telling you where to place the firebats. The interpretation would be "place 1 firebat", with no mention of where to place them.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I believed it was my interpretations for the same reasons; but all 5 other players kept saying I was wrong and it was really annoying, and because of me only starting with 1 firebat I had hardly any chance of winning. :)